# What is the difference in these two sentences?

Tags: adverbs

1. She foolishly answered the questions.
2. She answered the questions foolishly.

My notes says that adverbs when placed before the verb applies to the action but the meaning changes when it occurs after the verb. The problem is I can't understand the difference here.

Comment: Both have the same meaning, and they both are correct. The only difference is not in meaning or usage, but in the placement of adverb, "foolishly". The placement depends on the choice of the writer. That's all.

Comment: Then why does my note say that the meaning changes with the position of verb?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*She foolishly answered the questions* would mean *She should have kept her mouth shut*.

*She answered the questions foolishly* would mean *She gave idiotic answers to the questions.*

> She foolishly answered =  It was foolish to answer
>
> She answered foolishly =  She gave a foolish answer

Bond foolishly answered the question:

> Where's the microchip, Mr Bond?  Tell me now, and I'll spare your girlfriend's life.
>   -- It's in the dumpster, under the rotten potatoes.
>
> Shot fired. Bond dead.
>   Shot fired. Bond's girlfriend, dead.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.. BTW it was really hilarious.